# Mount an sshfs via macfuse at boot

Tags: macos, boot, mount, sshfs, macfuse

I want to mount an sshfs folder at boot under Mac OSX: I'm using Macfusion right now, that is a GUI for MacFUSE, but I have to mount the folder manually.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you maintain a remote machine, it can be really useful to mount that machine's filesystem locally to move files around. MacFuse and `sshfs` make this really easy, although getting it set up and mounted automatically at login can be a bit tricky.

First, make sure you can ssh to your remote machine without entering a password. Do the setup in [Leopard finally supporting ssh-agent at login](http://ormset.no/wordpress/2007/10/28/leopard-finally-supporting-ssh-agent-at-login) and verify that it works:

```
ssh USER@HOSTNAME:
```

If it logged you in without prompting for a password or passkey, you're ready to proceed.

Next, install `sshfs` and MacFuse as per [Installing sshfs 1.9 with MacFuse 1.7 on OS X Leopard 10.5.5](http://emmby.blogspot.com/2008/12/installing-sshfs-19-with-macfuse-17-on.html).

Figure out where you want to mount your remote volume. I wouldn't recommend using `/Volumes` since it appears that OS X automatically deletes directories in there when you unmount things. So instead I used `/mnt/HOSTNAME`

```
mkdir -p /mnt/HOSTNAME
```

(Obviously, you'll replace *`HOSTNAME`* with your remote server's name.)

Then make sure you can mount your remote site as a volume without specifying a password using `sshfs`:

```
sshfs USER@HOSTNAME:PATH /mnt/HOSTNAME -oreconnect,allow_other,volname=VOLUME_NAME
```

Set VOLUME_NAME to whatever you want your volume to be named in the Finder. I used HOSTNAME. PATH is optional; set it to whichever directory you want to mount on the remote host. If it's not set, it'll use your home directory.

If you get no error messages,
and when you do an `ls /mnt/HOSTNAME`
the remote files show up, then you're ready to proceed to the next step.

Unmount the volume you just mounted:

```
umount /mnt/HOSTNAME
```

Now comes the tricky party. You'll need to create a LaunchAgent item to mount your volume at login. This in itself is pretty easy. However, if your system is anything like mine, this item won't have its SSH_AUTH_SOCK set properly, so it won't be able to login to the remote host without using a password. You'll have to manually set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK yourself.

First, create a wrapper around `sshfs` that will set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK for you. Put this in a file wherever you want. 
I suggest `/opt/local/bin/sshfs-authsock`.

```
#!/bin/bash
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(ls -t /tmp/launch-*/Listeners | head -1)
/opt/local/bin/sshfs $*
```

Basically, this file sets SSH_AUTH_SOCK to the most recent socket in your tmp directory.  In most cases, this should be the proper one. It's unlikely to fail, and there's no security issue if it does.

Now you can finally create the launchd plist file. Put this in

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/BACKWARDS_HOST_DNS.PATH.sshfs.plist
```

(If your host's path is, say, `foo.niskala.org` and your PATH was `/tmp`, then your resulting filename would be `org.niskala.foo.tmp.sshfs.plist`. 
This is just a convention, feel free to name the file whatever you want,
really; but it does need to end in `.plist`.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>BACKWARDS_HOST_DNS.PATH.sshfs</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/opt/local/bin/sshfs-authsock</string>
                <string>USER@HOSTNAME:</string>
                <string>/mnt/HOSTNAME</string>
                <string>-oreconnect,allow_other,volname=VOLUME_NAME</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now load the plist file and run it to see if it works.

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/BACKWARDS_HOST_DNS.PATH.sshfs
launchctl start BACKWARDS_HOST_DNS.PATH.sshfs
```

If you see no error messages, see if the volume was mounted properly:

```
ls /mnt/HOSTNAME
```

If your remote files show up, then great! You're done!

If not, use

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/BACKWARDS_HOST_DNS.PATH.sshfs
```

to unload the file before making edits to it, then use `ps auxwww | grep sshfs` and `kill` to find and kill any `sshfs` processes before trying again.

References:

- http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1674891&tstart=22
- http://ccraig.org/sshfs-mac.html
- http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/MACFUSE_FS_SSHFS

Comment: Great guide -- thanks. One change is I had to add `.plist` to the end of the filepath to the `launchctl load` command, but the `launchctl start` command does not require the .plist extension. Also, I had forgotten to `chmod +x` my `sshfs-authsock` file (opening Console.app revealed this mistake.)

Comment: Sigh, in today's MacOS 10.15.5 update, SSH_AUTH_SOCK path changed to `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.*/Listeners`. (Just _once_ I want Apple to patch my OS without breaking things!)

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to update the great answer from dag729. On El Captain OS X with the OS X Fuse 2.8.3 the things are slightly different:

1. Some paths are changed
2. osxfuse must be forced to run in foreground mode with `-f` option
3. `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is already defined so there is no more reason to create the `sshfs-authsock` script

Also I would advice to don't use `allow_other` option (for security reasons) and use `auto_cache` option just because it sounds useful. Please check [OS X Fuse mount options](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options) for details.

Here is `~/Library/LaunchAgents/NAME.sshfs.plist` file that I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>NAME.sshfs</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/sshfs</string>
            <string>[USER@]HOST:REMOTE_DIR</string>
            <string>MOUNT_DIR</string>
            <string>-oreconnect,auto_cache,volname=FINDER_VOLUME_NAME</string>
            <string>-f</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Where `NAME` is any name you like and the rest variables are quite self descriptive.

---

If for some reason you don't have `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` defined (run command `launchctl getenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to check it) then create a helper script, for example `/usr/local/bin/sshfs-authsock` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(ls -t /tmp/com.apple.launchd.*/Listeners | head -1)
/usr/local/bin/sshfs $*
```

And run this script instead of `sshfs` from plist file. So your `~/Library/LaunchAgents/NAME.sshfs.plist` should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>NAME.sshfs</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/sshfs-authsock</string>
            <string>[USER@]HOST:REMOTE_DIR</string>
            <string>MOUNT_DIR</string>
            <string>-oreconnect,auto_cache,volname=FINDER_VOLUME_NAME</string>
            <string>-f</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add something to dag729's very complete answer.

If you have Lion and have now [OS X Fuse](http://osxfuse.github.com/) instead of the old MacFuse, then the procedure above won't work out of the box because the path of sshfs is different.

If that's the case for you, look where sshfs is in your installation using

```
which sshfs
```

and put *that* path in the /opt/local/bin/sshfs-authsock script.

In my installation, that path is /usr/local/bin/sshfs and therefore my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$( ls -t /tmp/launch-*/Listeners | head -1)
/usr/local/bin/sshfs $*
```

I can confirm that the rest is still valid.