# Accessing data on a cluster through ssh

Tags: macos, ssh, cluster

I have compute access on a mac pro, and am planning to get storage access on a linux based cluster to which I can ssh into.

Is it possible to use the mac pro for my compute needs, but keeping the data stored on the linux based cluster, accessing the data via ssh? My scripting is mostly in python, so this would necessiate some change in those scripts which have been accessing data locally till now.

Comment: There is a way to mount a remote file system so it appears to be available locally on the file system, I forgot how tho, maybe someone else in here knows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount an sshfs via macfuse at boot](http://superuser.com/questions/134140/mount-an-sshfs-via-macfuse-at-boot)